# Where does 'anchor keys list' store its keys?

Tags: anchor-lang

I know `anchor keys list` shows existing keys, or creates new ones. And `anchor keys sync` will modify my program to use the stored keys. But where are the `anchor keys list` keys stored on disk?

I've looked in the [Anchor Docs](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth) and been unable to find a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`anchor keys list` command reads all programs in the workspace and gets their pubkeys from the keypair files located in `target/deploy` directory.

Each keypair file name can be derived by combining the program lib name with `-keypair.json`, thus the keypair file path for each program is `target/deploy/<PROGRAM_LIB_NAME>-keypair.json`.

[Source](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/8f3bb8a5567047c7385adc25d3c8c0d7532aa01a/cli/src/config.rs#L1244)